# Google Line Chart rendering as empty, but no errors

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I don't know if I'm just losing my marbles, but: I'm trying to get a very simple Google Line Chart to render, and although Javascript isn't throwing any errors, the generated SVG is always effectively empty, with a height of around 21px.

Elsewhere on the site I have a page that, whenever you click on a `.region` link, it launches a lightbox, and within that lightbox is effectively the exact same Google Line Chart - the only difference is that its datapoints are plotted dynamically based on various `data` attributes of the clicked link. *This* works perfectly, and the code is virtually identical.

I initially figured I'd made a simple mistake, but I've recoded this thing at least 4 different ways, and none of them work. The only real difference is that this is graph is generated on page load via a `callback` function. I've also tried drawing it on a click event, within a `setTimeout`, abstracting it to another function altogether... but nothing works.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vfx5nohh/) of my code; and a snippet below if that's easier for anyone.

Hopefully I'm just tired and missing something glaringly obvious, but this has confounded me for the last few hours.

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {'callback': resultGraph, 'packages':['corechart']});

var chartData;
 
function resultGraph() {
    chartData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['Group',    'World'],
   ['',      0],
   ['Flash Laggards',   14.2],
   ['Flash Aware',   24.4],
   ['Flash Users',   36],
   ['Flash Innovators', 12.8],
   ['',      0],
  ]);
    var options = {
   legend: 'none',
   series: {
    0: { color: '#1976D2' },
   },
   chartArea: {
    left: '30',
    top: '30',
    width: '100%'
   },
   hAxis: {
    gridlines: {
     count: 3
    },
   },
  };
  
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('datachart'));
  
  chart.draw(chartData, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//www.google.com/jsapi?ver=1.0.1'></script>

Data chart:

<div id="datachart">
    <span>Loading...</span>
</div>
```

Comment: no idea why. but try removing your span. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LiranBo/Lbug9p9y/). the more I play with google charts - the more I hate it.

Comment: @LiranBo Ugh, for the love of god... _you're right_. All I did in my actual code was remove the `<span>` and it worked. It was pretty superfluous anyway, so if you want to add to your answer about the span within the element causing the issue, that might be helpful to other people slowly killing themselves with Google Charts.

Comment: wait till you start working on changing the tooltip (spoiler alert). this is the real nightmare with google charts.

Comment: As an addendum to this: I gave up with Google Charts and went for High Charts instead. Way, _way_ easier to deal with, and I got the exact effect I was looking for in about 5 minutes, compared to losing a day and a head of hair with Google Charts. Bad Google. Bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, I don't know why it is caused, but I can offer [this simple fix](http://jsfiddle.net/LiranBo/vfx5nohh/1/)

**JS change**

```
function resultGraph() {
    $("#datachart").empty();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The chart is actually not rendering empty, it's just rendering to small.

When the div

```
<div id="datachart">
    <span>Loading...</span>
</div>
```

is rendered it's rendered in the size of about 65x17pxs. When the SVG element is rendered into that 65x17 div, it doesn't enlarge the div, thus rendering in a div that won't show it, cause it's to small.

When you remove the span (I can't really explain this, cause I don't really understand it either) the SVG elements are able to enlarge the div.

So you can either work with this by setting the size of your div from the start, like

```
style="width:700px; height:250px;"
```

or setting the size of the chart in the options

```
var options = {
        width:700,
        height:250
    }
```

or as your last option you could of course just remove the span right before drawing the chart.

```
document.getElementById('datachart').innerHTML = '';        
chart.draw(chartData, options);
```

EDIT:
I couldn't drop this, so I played around a bit more. Apparantly it's enough to just float the span, and then the chart will render in the correct site. Absolute/fixed positioning works as well.

So a fourth solution would be to add `style="float:left"` to your span, or perhaps a reusable class like

```
.preChartText {
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I did wonder if this was the case initially, but screwing with the dimensions in the inspector didn't seem to show anything. Regardless, unfortunately I can't hardcode the dimensions as it needs to behave responsively, so I went with simply removing the span.